# ¿Que signifca '$variable1 -a $variable2' dentro de un if en bash?

Tags: bash, condiciones, shell-script

Lei que la opcion `-a [Archivo]` dentro de una condicion es verdadera si el archivo existe, pero ahora me encuentro con esto y me doy cuenta de que la opcion `-a` no tiene nada que ver con la explicacion anterior:

```
var1=1
var2=2
[ "$var1" -a "$var2" ] && echo true || echo false
```

El output es `true` y yo no tengo ningun fichero con nombre "1" ni "2"; Ahora cuando alguna de las dos variables o las dos estan vacias entonces:

```
var1=1
var2=""
[ "$var1" -a "$var2" ] && echo true || echo false
```

El output ahora es `false`.

No entiendo que es lo que esta haciendo la opción `-a`. Estoy leyendo un código y usa ese tipo de validación, alguien que me explique: **¿Cuál es la función de esa opción?**

Ya que no encontré nada mas en internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La opción *-a* es  un AND lógico alternativo  al &&.  Tambien existe  *-o* como  alternativa al ||.

En tu ejemplo:

```
  var1=1
  var2=2
```

La  condición de verdadero/falso se da mediante el contenido de la variable o por alguna  expresión logica. En la expresion:

```
 [ "$var1" -a "$var2" ]
```

Se evalua  var1 y var2 como verdadero  si tiene algún valor, por lo tanto,

se transforma en [verdadero y verdadero] da como resultado verdadero. Por eso imprime "true".

En  el segundo caso var2 no  tiene valor por lo tanto en una condicional es falso, entonces, la condición:

```
    [ "$var1" -a "$var2" ]
```

es [verdadero y falso] da como resultado "false".

Answer (score 2):

Buenísima pregunta pero atrevida (y errónea) interpretación de lo que leíste.

### TL;DR

No es lo mismo `[ -a parametro1 ]` que `[ parametro1 -a parametro2 ]`. Bash lo interpreta de maneras diferentes.

El primero opera sobre archivos, y el segundo como un operador AND lógico.

### Explicación detallada

La clave aquí está en el operador `[`. Este operador es un alias del built-in `test`:

```
$ help [
[: [ arg... ]
    Evaluate conditional expression.

    This is a synonym for the "test" builtin, but the last argument must
    be a literal `]', to match the opening `['.
```

Entonces, cuando vemos en `man 5 bash`, encontramos que `test`, `[` y `[[`, permiten la evalución de expresiones condicionales.

En la sección de `test`, se especifica cómo serán evaluadas las expresiones si tienen, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 o más argumentos. En este caso, como tenemos 2 argumentos (el parámetro `-a` y el archivo), encontramos que se habla sobre operadores *unarios*, es decir, que reciben como parámetro **un sólo valor**, y que serán evaluadas conforme a lo establecido a `CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS`.

En la sección de `CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS`, encontramos esto:

```
-a file   
    True if file exists.
```

Es decir, devuelve 0 (*true*, o salida exitosa en el caso de Bash) si encontró el archivo, u otro valor si no lo encontró.

Sin embargo, cuando escribes algo de la forma `[ parametro1 -a parametro2 ]`, ya estamos hablando de **tres argumentos**, entonces la operación es **binaria**, en la que el primer valor (`parametro1`) y el tercer valor (`parametro2`) serán tomados como los valores a evaluar según el segundo valor (el operador; en este caso `-a`).

En la misma sección de `test`, se establece que cuando se tiene la forma `[ parámetro1 -a parámetro2 ]`, tiene una salida exitosa ("devuelve" True) si ambos parámetros son ciertos; es decir, funciona como un *AND* lógico.

### Conclusión

Bash no te adivina el pensamiento. Tienes que actuar conforme al manual de Bash y de cada programa.

En Bash importan mucho las posiciones, la tokenización (cadenas divididas según el valor de la variable `IFS`) y la sintaxis.

Tus mejores amigos son la tecla TAB y el manual (`man bash`, `help <builtin>`,
`<builtin> --help`).